# Security considerations for buying a used OSX machine?

Tags: macos, security

Im looking at a used OSX machine, but have concerns over security of a used machine. The machine in question is a 2012 Macbook Pro laptop, with a removable HD and Ram and battery, this is one of the last models that Apple made that is user serviceable.

I was planning on re flashing the HDD from a HDD i already have, but other than that any things i should do / be aware of ?

My main concerns would be pre loaded malware, either software or malware hardware. Eg. key loggers, screen readers etc. As well as concerns of someone leaving a back door into the system, to access my data stored on the device. These would be the concerns i could perceive but would be keen to know if there should be other things i should be think about.

Comment: What threats are you worried about specifically?

Comment: Formatting all disks should be protection enough.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think it's unreasonable to ask if there are any additional security considerations beyond formatting the disk. Many devices nowadays have data that persists outside of the OS and HDD, such as EFI, SMC, and other low-level configuration. I'd always recommend resetting the BIOS settings if you're getting a second-hand PC, for example.

Comment: @Ramhound question updated to add my concerns, but not sure if this is a full list of potential threats.

Comment: Not a security issue, but [be aware that some 2012 Macbook Pros had hardware issues](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/).

Comment: Oh I had one of those faulty discrete GPU ones and it really sucked after a year or two. You think they'd learn, I found an old iBook that had inverted screen colors because of a similar GPU failure, like a decade earlier (with a similar recall notice to boot). I always recommend not buying the first generation of a new Apple product design if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 8):

Apple themselves only recommend formatting the HDDs/SSDs before giving your Mac away, so safe to say you can just do that when you obtain a used one. This specifically is really no different for a Mac than it is a PC.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

However I would also say that you should reset the SMC (System Management Controller) to make sure there's no remaining weird configuration or settings left over.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

## Resetting SMC

If the battery is nonremovable:

```
1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.  
2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power button.  
3. Release all keys.  
4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
```

If the battery is removable:

```
1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
4. Reinstall the battery.
5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
```

Comment: It would be preferable to quote/include the relevant parts of the linked pages in case those links were to break.